# Python Requests: page expiring

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to get the XUID (think uuid) for an xbox account using this site: https://cxkes.me/xbox/xuid
My problem is I keep running into this message: "The page has expired due to inactivity."
I'm not sure what I need to pass to this site for this message to go away. I am using sessions, I tried setting the referer url to the same url. Quite frankly, I just don't know what is required and where I should pass it. Cookies, headers, or data.
Here is my headers/data:

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36', 'referer': 'https://cxkes.me/xbox/xuid'}
data = {"gamertag":"pl", resolve: "Resolve", '_token':'kOjVfYKVjMV2DRycu7qSZZEOm07BMDlCJrrtkpTE'}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The page has expired due to inactivity." seems to be Laravel's way of saying your CSRF token is invalid.

Most likely you'll need to:

- use a Requests session so you have cookie storage for cookies
- GET https://cxkes.me/xbox/xuid first
- grab the `_token` value from there
- POST using that `_token` value (and the cookies you've been sent)

and things should hopefully work.